# PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values when creating function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am creating a package with a function that returns a table. Here is the (simplified) code:

```
DROP TYPE A_TABLE;
 /
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE A_RECORD IS object (
    ID  varchar(10),
    Name    varchar(500)
);
/ 
CREATE  TYPE A_TABLE IS TABLE OF A_RECORD;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE My_Package AS

  results A_TABLE;

  FUNCTION A_Data() 
  RETURN A_TABLE;

END My_Package;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY My_Package IS 

  FUNCTION A_Data() RETURN A_TABLE IS results A_TABLE;

  BEGIN

    SELECT ID,Name
    BULK COLLECT INTO results 
    FROM Customer_Table customer

  RETURN results;

  END A_Data;

END My_Package;
/
```

I get this error on compiling the package:

```
Error(9,13): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
```

The query itself works although there is no data in there at the moment as the database is being worked on at the moment. I can't understand why this is breaking. I think it might be something to do with types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select two values into one record. It not work that way. You should create your record type in your select:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY My_Package IS 

  FUNCTION A_Data() RETURN A_TABLE IS results A_TABLE;

  BEGIN

    SELECT A_RECORD(ID,Name)
    BULK COLLECT INTO results 
    FROM Customer_Table customer

  RETURN results;

  END A_Data;

END My_Package;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is

```
SELECT ID,Name  -- here
BULK COLLECT INTO results 
FROM Customer_Table customer
```

The objects of type A_RECORD need to be collected in result. so, call should be

```
SELECT A_RECORD(ID,Name) BULK ...`
```

Besides, I think you don't really need to create types externally. This should work:

```
create or replace PACKAGE My_Package AS
  TYPE A_TABLE IS TABLE OF Customr_Table%rowtype;

  FUNCTION A_Data
  RETURN A_TABLE;

END My_Package;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY My_Package
IS
FUNCTION A_Data
  RETURN A_TABLE
IS
  results A_TABLE;
BEGIN
  SELECT ID, NAME BULK COLLECT INTO results FROM Customr_Table;
  RETURN results;
END A_Data;
END My_Package;
/
```

And you can use it like this:

```
declare
  v My_Package.A_Table;
begin
  v := My_Package.A_data();
  for i in 1 .. v.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(v(i).id || ' ' || v(i).Name);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: I believe I need to specify types externally if I intend to call the function from outside the package no?

Comment: @Damien Updated my answer.

Comment: Cheers, in this case it was the answer below but you've provided some info I didn't know too. Thanks.